# Iteration in Matlab

Tags: matlab, iteration, differential-equations, equation-solving

I want to solve some iteration in chemical engineering problem using matlab.
So the problem that I want to solve is Calculating the inter convertion of series adiabatic reactors, here is the algorithm given:

> 1. [Algorthm in reactor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLRSm.png)
>
> [Algorithm in reactor 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azp8g.png)
>
> 2. [Algotirhm in reactor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkW9V.png)
>
> [Algorithm in reactor 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urr2E.png)

I have been solved it in VBA Excel and the code is:

```
Public Function intrap(h, y)
n = y.Count
If n Mod 2 > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("JUMLAH DATA HARUS GENAP")
    intrap = "ERROR:JUMLAH DATA HARUS GENAP"
Exit Function
End If

For i = 1 To n
s1 = s1 + y(i)
Next i

For i = 2 To (n - 1)
s2 = s2 + y(i)
Next i

intrap = (h / 2) * (y(1) + (2 * s2) + y(n))
End Function
```

and the output is
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoLCn.png)

So, how to do it in matlab?

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:

```
function result = intrap(h, y)
    n = length(y);
    if n % 2 > 0
        disp("JUMLAH DATA HARUS GENAP")
        result = 'ERROR:JUMLAH DATA HARUS GENAP';
        return
    end

    for i = 1:n
        s1 = s1 + y(i);
    end

    for i = 2:(n - 1)
        s2 = s2 + y(i);
    end

    result = (h / 2) * (y(1) + (2 * s2) + y(n));
end
```

Id recommend you doing a few tutorials. You'll see that Matlab is pretty straight forward for easy programming.

Sheers